# React Ant design Table- Customize the search filter

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-table-v6

I am trying to customize the search filter in React Ant design table, typically ant design allows customizable dropdown for search filter, for [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/67nho). But the requirement is to show permanent search boxes under the columns similar to the [react table by Tanner](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6/examples/custom-filtering), rather than a dropdown.

I tried to pass a ReactNode in title prop for columns, but it creates weird onClick side effects. Is there a way to customize the header?

Comment: You can add a separate row for the search bards which will be there by default in the table data array. And add onChange, onSubmit events on them.

Comment: Thanks, How can we pass the input component in row data? I did something like this:

  const transformData = (columns, data = []) => {
    const col = {};
    columns.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.searchable) col[element.title] = <Input />;
    });
    return [col, ...data];
  };

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it simple, you can create the first row as:

```
getFieldsForEachColumn = (columns) => {
const row = {};
columns.forEach((element, index) => {
  if (element.searchable) {
    const inputFieldCell = (
      <Input onChange={(e) => this.handleOnChange(e.target.value, element.title)}/>
    );
    row[Object.keys(data[0])[index + 1]] = inputFieldCell
  } else {
    row[Object.keys(data[0])[index + 1]] = null;
  }
});
return row;
```

};

And then when you are mapping the array data, just push this returned in the started of that array.

Comment: I tried this but nothing renders under the header...
[https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-morse-k2byg?file=/index.js]

Comment: I have made some changes to your code. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you please post changes here, I cant see changes in code sandbox

Comment: I have updated my answer above, The function would look like this. You can styled the input field. Also the data variable used in the above method is the the actual data.